# Mystery while driving a NeoPixel Ring (WS2812) with a GEMMA (ATtiny85)

Tags: avr, attiny, rgb, avr-gcc

I am working with an [Adafruit GEMMA](http://www.adafruit.com/gemma) and [NeoPixel Ring](http://www.adafruit.com/products/1463) 16 LEDs (ATtiny85 and 16 WS2812 leds) and trying to get a program to light the LEDs according to my "pattern" structure below, representing R, G, B, R, G, B, R, G, B.

The code below works but you can see it's not "proper code" what I am aiming for is that the `while(1)` loop looks like this:

```
 while(1)
    {
      k++;
      for (i = 0; i < NUM_LEDS; i++) {
        uint8_t l = (i+k) % (PATTERN_LEN);
        uint8_t idx = l * 3; 
        set_color(buf, i, pattern[idx], pattern[idx+1], pattern[idx+2]);
      }
      if (k == NUM_LEDS * 10) k = 0;
      output_grb(buf, sizeof(buf));
      _delay_ms(90);
    }
```

However when I flash this code I get what looks more like a random: I get red red magenta blue green and it changes...

Code that Actually does what I expect which is a set of red LEDs decreasing on intensity and circling around is the one below, which I think should be doing the exact same as the one above.

I am at a loss on how to debug/diagnose the issue, I suspect is related to the compiler but not sure what to change or how to test.

The only difference between the two approaches is in the `while(1)` loop

Any pointers are welcome.

```
#define F_CPU   8000000

#include <avr/io.h>
#include <util/delay.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h> 

#define NUM_LEDS      16
#define BUF_SIZE      (NUM_LEDS * 3)
#define PATTERN_LEN   8

const uint8_t pattern[PATTERN_LEN * 3] = {
  70, 0, 0 , 
  60, 0, 0 , 
  50, 0, 0, 
  40, 0, 0 , 
  30, 0, 0 , 
  20, 0, 0 , 
  10, 0, 0 , 
  0,  0, 0
}; 

// declaration of our ASM function
extern void output_grb(uint8_t * ptr, uint16_t count);

void set_color(uint8_t * p_buf, uint8_t led, uint8_t r, uint8_t g, uint8_t b)
{
  uint16_t index = 3*led;
  p_buf[index++] = g/2;
  p_buf[index++] = r/2;
  p_buf[index] = b/2;  
}

int main(void)
{
    uint8_t buf[BUF_SIZE];

    // set PORTB0 as output.-   
    DDRB = 0b00000001;   // bit 0 is our output

    // Init to 0, all leds off     
    memset(buf, 0, sizeof(buf));
    output_grb(buf, sizeof(buf));
    uint8_t i,k = 0;

    while(1)
    {
      k++;
      for (i = 0; i < NUM_LEDS; i++) {
        uint8_t l = (i+k) % (PATTERN_LEN);
        uint8_t idx = l * 3; 
        switch (idx) 
        {
          case 0:
            set_color(buf, i, pattern[idx], pattern[idx+1], pattern[idx+2]);
            break;          
          case 3:
            set_color(buf, i, pattern[idx], pattern[idx+1], pattern[idx+2]);
            break;          
          case 6:
            set_color(buf, i, pattern[idx], pattern[idx+1], pattern[idx+2]);
            break;          
          case 9:
            set_color(buf, i, pattern[idx], pattern[idx+1], pattern[idx+2]);
            break;          
          case 12: 
            set_color(buf, i, pattern[idx], pattern[idx+1], pattern[idx+2]);
            break;          
          case 15: 
            set_color(buf, i, pattern[idx], pattern[idx+1], pattern[idx+2]);
            break;          
          case 18: 
            set_color(buf, i, pattern[idx], pattern[idx+1], pattern[idx+2]);
            break;          
          case 21: 
            set_color(buf, i, pattern[idx], pattern[idx+1], pattern[idx+2]);
            break;          
          default:
            set_color(buf, i, 0, 0, 0);
            break;
        }
      }
      if (k == NUM_LEDS * 10) k = 0;
      output_grb(buf, sizeof(buf));
      _delay_ms(90);
    }
}
```

Comment: Here is a link to the "working" version http://youtu.be/ofdSMRgt3oI and one to the failed one: http://youtu.be/ikrFgImaMSs

Comment: If I understand correctly, you are expecting only varying intensities (8) of red, but green and blue are also being lit?

Comment: that's correct. JYelton

Comment: I haven't been able to find any flaws that would result in writing to green or blue. I'm not sure what the variable `k` is for. I noticed that first time through the loop, `i` is 0, `k` is 1, `idx` is 3, thus `set_color()` uses indices 3 through 5 of the pattern array instead of 0 through 2; not that it probably matters much.

Comment: @webclimber: Is it possible the ring is GRB instead of RGB? Or even RGBW?